# primefaces selectOneMenu ajax even on click not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I am unable to get the ajax event click to work with primefaces selectOneMenu. Using the latest primefaces 11.0. The documentation states that these are available ajax events: blur, change, click, dblclick, focus, itemSelect, keydown, keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove, mouseout, mouseover, mouseup, select, valueChange.

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{beam.event}" editable="false" id="event">
    <f:selectItems value="#{beam.events}"/>
    <p:ajax event="click" onstart="console.log('start 1');" immediate="true" listener="#{beam.onClick}" update="@this"/>
    <p:ajax event="click" onstart="console.log('start 2');" immediate="true" listener="#{beam.onClickNoParam}" update="@this"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

The onstart client side callbacks are not triggered. The beam listeners look like this:

```
public void onClick(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    System.out.println("onClick");
}

public void onClickNoParam() {
    System.out.println("onClick");
}
```

I did get the focus event to work, but it is triggered way to many times and unfortunately in combination with the the update one gets stuck in an endless recursive loop.

I don't notice any issues when the click event is registered by the AjaxBehaviorHandler/AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl compared to the focus event.

Comment: It must be a bug with the "click" AJAX event I habe to admit it my career I have never used a "click" AJAX event. What exactly are you trying to do most of the time the "change" or "itemSelect" events are what you want on an autoComplete when someone selects and item?

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that not many use this event in combination with selectOneMenu. I am trying to fetch new values before displaying the dropdown menu.

Comment: Oh don't do it like that. That case is handled already look at the Showcase "POJO (Rest)" example here: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml  its exacly what you want a dynamically filled list right?

Comment: Thank you, will give autoComplete another try, I did manage to get it working as described above but couldn't use it for a different reason.

Comment: Hi @krizajb could you provide the solution, I have also a problem with the click event.

Comment: Hi @MladenB, the above comment is for the POJO approach. The click event remains a mystery to me. I did end up debugging quite a lot, but gave up in the end. Same goes for the dynamic dropdown(s). The project was put on hold for those reasons.